# react-native(mobX) : How to add a new object to existing object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx

I am trying to add a `new object` to existing `object`.

**In my `mobx Store` I have an existing object which contains `one user`:**

```
@observable user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'kevin@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'kevin',
        address: {
            city: 'Costa Mesa',
            state: 'CA'
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to add another user to existing object:**

```
id: 102,
    email: 'john@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'john',
        address: {
            city: 'New York',
            state: 'NY'
        }

    }
```

**I want my final code to look like this:**

```
@observable user = {
    id: 101,
    email: 'kevin@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'kevin',
        address: {
            city: 'Costa Mesa',
            state: 'CA'
        }
    },
    id: 102,
    email: 'john@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'john',
        address: {
            city: 'New York',
            state: 'NY'
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the correct format to add another object to the existing object?

Would this work?

```
updateObjectState (){

const user2 = {
  id: 102,
  email: 'john@dev.com',
  personalInfo: {
      name: 'john',
      address: {
          city: 'New York',
          state: 'NY'
      }
  }
}
  store.pressedDate = [...store.pressedDate, user2] 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your desired result can't be achieved, as `id` is repeated so it will overwrite last `id`, wrap each user in object or use array

Comment: @CodeManiac thanks for the comment. Could you please guide me how to do it? Showing an example would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired result can't be achieved, as id is repeated so it will overwrite last id, wrap each user in object or use array

using `id` as key and placing values, when you want to add new user just create a new key value pair on user

```
@observable user = {
    '101':{
           id: 101,
           email: 'kevin@dev.com',
           personalInfo: {
           name: 'kevin',
           address: {
             city: 'Costa Mesa',
             state: 'CA'
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Or having user as an array, to add new user just push the value in user

```
@observable user = [{
    id: 101,
    email: 'kevin@dev.com',
    personalInfo: {
        name: 'kevin',
        address: {
            city: 'Costa Mesa',
            state: 'CA'
        }
    }
}]
```

**P.S** - I am not sure how you're using data, but i will go with the object way,

Comment: I am sorry, I think my question wasn't clear. I wanted to have a function that adds the `second object` to the `existing object` Would me edited code work?

Comment: @kirimi yeah that's totally fine if you're storing as array, if your storing as object, then you can use `store.pressedDate = {...store.pressedDate, [user2.id]: user2 }`